# Jupyter Notebook throws a user warning when accessing local dataset

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, computer-vision, jupyter, conv-neural-network

I am running my notebook locally to use my own GPU. As opposed to Colab, I am having some issues with the local instance. When I run this cell:

```
np.random.seed(42)
data = ImageList.from_folder(path).split_by_rand_pct(valid_pct=0.2).label_from_re(pat=file_parse).transform(size=224).databunch()
```

I’m getting this error:

```
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change "
```

Due to this problem, I can't run any CNN learning epoch as the moment I run that cell, the above error comes and training stops before it even began.

```
top_1 = partial(top_k_accuracy, k=1)
learn = cnn_learner(data, models.resnet50, metrics=[accuracy, top_1], callback_fns=ShowGraph)
learn.fit_one_cycle(5)
```

And this is the output:

```
 0.00% [0/5 00:00<00:00]
epoch   train_loss  valid_loss  accuracy    top_k_accuracy  time

 0.00% [0/946 00:00<00:00]

/home/onur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2854: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor will change in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and use scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to keep the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a version issues. There are two ways to approach this.

1. One is to use compatible versions, which you can do by running this :

`pip install "torch==1.4" "torchvision==0.5.0"`

2. Another thing would be to set `recompute_scale_factor=True` in line 540 of `fastai/vision/image.py`

Replace `F.interpolate(x[None], scale_factor=1/d, mode='area')` by `F.interpolate(x[None], scale_factor=1/d, mode='area', recompute_scale_factor=True)`